# Generate joined image from a list of images

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

I have created a method that could join a list of images together to form a single image.

The code can handle only 4 images right now which i want to change it so that it could handle more then 4.

I'm trying to create a simple way to do it.

Here is the code. Is there a simple way of doing it?

```
    public static byte[] CombineImages(params string[] imageUrl)
    {
        var staticWidth = 200;
        var staticHeight = 200;
        // download the images from the url and then resize them
        List<Bitmap> images = imageUrl
            .Select((x, i) => i <= 3 ? GenerateThumbImage(GetImage(x), staticWidth, staticHeight) : null)
            .Where(x => x != null).ToList();
        var nIndex = 0;
        var max_Height = 0;
        var max_Width = 0;
        var counter = 0;
        foreach (var image in images)
        {
            max_Height = Math.Max(max_Height, image.Height);
            if (counter <= 1)
                max_Width += image.Width;
            counter++;
        }

        // the container of the joined images
        var imgContainer = new Bitmap(max_Width, imageUrl.Count() > 2 ? max_Height * 2 : max_Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        var g = Graphics.FromImage(imgContainer);
        g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
        // and here is where i need your help to simplify it 
        // and make it more dynamic so it could handle more then 4 images
        for (var i = 0; i < images.Count(); i++)
        {
            var img = images[i];
            if (i == 0 || nIndex == 0)
            {
                g.DrawImage(img, new Point(0, i == 0 ? 0 : max_Height));
                max_Width = img.Width;
            }
            else
            {
                g.DrawImage(img, new Point(max_Width, i > 2 ? max_Height : 0));
                max_Width += img.Width;
            }

            if (nIndex >= 1)
                nIndex = 0;
            else nIndex++;
            img.Dispose();
        }

        g.Dispose();

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            imgContainer.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            return memoryStream.ToArray();
            //var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
            //img3.Dispose();
            //return base64String;
        }
    }
```

Comment: So whats the problem

Comment: So you want to tile them onto a larger image? You'll have to at least give some kind of pattern in which to join them. Either you approximate a square, or you give a maximum width to tile in, I guess?

Comment: Closing as Needs Details - there is no specific problem statement here.